# Download verification in a custom Qt based updater

Tags: c++, encryption, download, rsa, verification

I am the author of a desktop application that has an integrated updater that can download a new version of the app over the internet. I would like to authenticate the downloaded file so that the downloader can be sure that the new file was created by me and was not modified by someone else. SSL based server authentication isn't an option because the files are hosted on 3rd party service I do not neccesarily trust.

I have thought of the following procedure:

On my side:

- Hash the download using SHA512
- Encrypt the hash using a private RSA key
- Make the encrypted hash public along with the new version announcement

The updater on the client then does the following:

- Download the file (duh)
- Decrypt the hash from the new update announcement using a hardcoded public key matching my private one
- Compare the decrypted hash with the real one of the downloaded file

Are there any flaws in this workflow, assuming that I initially can deliver an unmodified version of the updater with the public key inside to the client?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using traditional code signing which already checks the boxes you're wanting. While your home-brewed solution may work, it isn't bulletproof without review. Proven cryptography is almost always the better way to do things.

You've got the right idea using public key cryptography. This is what I would suggest:

Either buy a code signing certificate through a CA (useful if you want to also meet Windows SmartScreen requirements) or generate a public-private key pair on your own. If you're self-signing, ship the public key along with the program. Sign any new installer using the private key. On upgrade, have the updater verify the signature using the public key before unpacking the new version. If your application is Windows-based, you can use [WinVerifyTrust](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208(v=vs.85).aspx) to verify.

Alternatively, the solution you propose has already been implemented via [PGP signing](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) which has withstood decades of security vetting already. You would simply publish the .sig with a new version and the updater would verify that. It has also been solved using [digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) which can be implemented simply via [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying).